# axioms of additive categories

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

One of the axioms of additive categories is the following:

(Axiom A3) For any pair of objects $X_1,X_2$ there exist an object $Y$ and morphisms $p_1,p_2,i_1,i_2$

\begin{equation*}X_1\xrightarrow{i_1} Y\xleftarrow{i_2} X_2,\ X_1\xleftarrow{p_1}Y\xrightarrow{p_2}X_2\end{equation*}

with the following properties:

$p_1i_1=id_{X_1}$, $p_2i_2=id_{X_2}$, $p_2i_1=p_1i_2=0$, $i_1p_1+i_2p_2=id_Y$

Gelfand's Homological algebra states that this axiom can be reformulated by saying that two sqaures below are respectively cartesian and cocartesian:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Y @>{p_1}>> X_1\\
@Vp_2VV @VVV \\
X_2 @>{}>> 0
\end{CD}
and
\begin{CD}
0 @>{}>> X_1\\
@VVV @VVi_1V \\
X_2 @>{i_2}>> Y
\end{CD}
I was able to prove that the condition from the axiom A3 implies that two squares are respectively cartesian and cocartesian but I am unable to prove the opposite direction. Can you please help?

Comment: This equivalence holds only on the base of the remaining axioms, of course. After all, with *only* the pushback/pullout diagram given, there is no way to give meaning to $i_1p_1\color{red}+i_2p_2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Of course, we have that $Hom(X,Y)$ is an Abelian group for every $X,Y$ and that category contains zero object $0$ such that $Hom(0,0)$ is trivial group. But still I don't know how to prove the equivalence.

Comment: As stated this seems to be false. Consider an abelian group $X$ and set $Y=X\oplus X$ take $p_1$ and $p_2$ the usual projections but take $i_1(x)=(x,x)$ and $i_2(x)=(0,x)$. You can still check both diagrams are as required but $p_2i_1 \neq 0$.